# implement exit item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation template of android studio in my project. I have two items to navigate through fragments and I added another item to exit the app via finish() method. The problem is this component doesn't use onNavigationItemSelected and when I try to use navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener() my exit item works fine but fragment switching doesn't work any more.

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
    binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_setting)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to be hard unless you paste some code as an example.

Comment: I updated my codes'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [Martin Marconcini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684/martin-marconcini) . Solution is :

```
NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(dest, navController)
```

Here's the piece of code that helped me :

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull @NotNull MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_exit) {
                finish();
            } else {
                NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController);
                drawer.closeDrawers();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great answer, that works for me. I had to call `drawerLayout.close()` instead of `drawer.closeDrawers()`, don't know if the API changed or `drawer`is something else than the DrawerLayout.